# How connect flutter to laragon

Tags: flutter, laragon

I'm doing a project for college and I'm using the laravel framework to build my website and the flutter framework to build the app that will help the website. As it is a local only job I want to use a local database so I chose Laragon. For the Website it is working very well, but for the App I am not able to find information that helps me to connect flutter and Laragon.

I don't know if it is possible to make this connection or if there is another way?

Ps: I didn't want to change to a database like firebase so as not to be changing all the work that is already done on the website

Thank you for the help!

---

---

I found another way to connect without using laravel. However it might be less secure I'm not sure but why is it what I need to get ahead at work.

But I'm having a problem with response.body

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:testedb/userd.dart';
import 'package:mysql1/mysql1.dart';


class UsersPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const UsersPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<UsersPage> createState() => _UsersPageState();
}

class _UsersPageState extends State<UsersPage> {
  List<User> users = [];
  void _fetch() async {
    
   var settings = ConnectionSettings(
  host: '10.0.2.2', 
  port: 3306,
  user: 'raf',
  password: '123',
  db: 'bd'
);
var conn = await MySqlConnection.connect(settings);
var response = await conn.query('select * from posts');
print(response);
final responseData = jsonDecode(response.body);


setState((){
    users = responseData.map((e) => User.fromJson(e)).toList();
});
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          ...users.map((user) => ListTile(
            leading: Container(
              height: 50,
              width: 50,
              child: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage("${user.image}"),
              ),
            ),
            title: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text("${user.name}"),
                Text("${user.age}", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),),
                SizedBox(height: 7,),
              ],
            ),
            subtitle: Text(user.race, maxLines: 2, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,),
          ),),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: _fetch, tooltip: 'Fetch Data', child: Icon(Icons.cloud_download),),
    );
  }
}
```

I get the correct answer, but I think I'm not converting correctly to the list (see the error response.body)

Comment: Could you let me know what the problem you're having? You can call API using http package. And also be sure to replace localhost with 10..0.2.2 in the API endpoints

Comment: but if I put for example "http://10.0.2.2:80/github/project/public/posts"
all the php code of the posts page is returned.

Comment: To receive only the data do I have to create a page with only the data in json format? I tried to do that but then I went to see it and when I got to the answer on the cell phone, some things were deformed

Comment: Could you explain how deformed they are? Did you use api routes and return response()->json() in your controller?

Comment: I added a new point to the question